# How to print minimal value from two dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

Hello everyone here is my code:

```
n =[[34,2,55,24,22],[31,22,4,7,333]]
for r in n:
   for c in r:
      print(c,end = " ")
   print()
   
sums=[]

for i in n:
  sum=0
  for num in i:
    sum+=int(num)
  sums.append(sum)
print(*sums)


    
mini = min([min(r) for r in n])
print(mini)
#This is what it prints out
 34 2 55 24 22 
 31 22 4 7 333 
 137 397
 2
```

As you can see it prints out smallest number from all array how i can print out smallest number from both rows i have tried using numpy but i have error and then i need to do something to files to fix it which i dont want to do can you please tell me another solution Last thing i need to print it out by changing rows like this and then all other stuff:

```
31 22 4 7 333
34 2 55 24 22
137 397
4 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to get the minimum of each row, not the minimum of that.

```
print(*(min(row) for row in n))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy

```py
>>> n = np.array([[34,2,55,24,22],[31,22,4,7,333]])
>>> n.min(axis=1)
array([2, 4])
>>>
```